# Express some french text into mathematical form

Tags: set-theory, translation-request, equivariant-maps, mathematical-french

I would like to express those text ( Original text is in french ) into mathematical form

$1$. The map $$Z\longmapsto \bar{A} \cup Z $$ is a bijection of the set of
All the parts $Z$ of $A$ on the set of the parts $X$ of $E$
Such that $X \cup A = E$.

**In mathematical form** :
\begin{align*}
1: \{ \mathcal{P}\left(A\right)\} &\rightarrow \{\mathcal{P}\left(X \right)\mid X\subset E: X\cup A=E\}\\
   Z&\mapsto \overline{A}\cup Z
 \end{align*}

$2$.The map $$Z\longmapsto (A\cap B ) \cup Z $$ is a bijection of the set of parts of $(A\cup B )\setminus (A\cap B)$ onto the set of parts X of E such that $A\cap B \subset X \subset A\cup B$.

**In mathematical form** :
\begin{align*}
2: \{ \mathcal{P}\left((A\cup B )\setminus (A\cap B)\right)\} &\rightarrow \{\mathcal{P}\left(X \right)\mid X\subset E: A\cap B \subset X \subset A\cup B\}\\
   Z&\mapsto (A\cap B ) \cup Z 
 \end{align*}

**Original text in french :**

[image]

Comment: You've written the domains and images of the maps. I don't think there's widely used notation to say that a given map is a bijection, so unless you want to go into unreadable hardcore "for all, there exists" territory that's about as good as it gets.

Comment: my aim is just to express french text in mathematical form coudl you do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the sets $A$, $B$, and  $E$ are given. So, I think it is better to define two new sets :
$$\mathcal{C}=\{ X\in \mathcal{P}(E)|  X\cup A=E  \}$$
and
$$\mathcal{D}=\{ X\in \mathcal{P}(E)|  A\cap B \subset X \subset A\cup B \}$$

Then the two maps  :

1. \begin{align*}
    \mathcal{P}\left(A\right) \rightarrow  \mathcal{C} \\
      Z \mapsto \overline{A}\cup Z
    \end{align*}
   and
2. \begin{align*}
   \mathcal{P}\left((A\cup B )\setminus (A\cap B)\right) &\rightarrow \mathcal{D}\\
      Z&\mapsto (A\cap B ) \cup Z 
    \end{align*}
   are bijective.

Comment: De rien  ;)  @Educ